# maven assembly throwing stackoverflowerror

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, stack-overflow

Hi denizens of stackoverflow,

I am having an issue with maven, specifically with the assembly phase. I have a large multi-module legacy project that unfortunately has some circular references within its submodules. It has been retrofitted to build with maven, but to refactor the circular references out would take too long.

The project builds fine by running mvn install, and even runs mvn package without issue, but fails when running mvn package assembly:assembly. Trying to run it with assembly:single gives me a build failure due to "Error creating assembly archive distrib: You must set at least one file".

With assembly:assembly, it seems to be processing the same libraries over and over again, eventually throwing a stackoverflowerror. I'm guessing this means that the circular references in the modules is causing this, though since it compiles with no issues, I had hope it would survive assembly as well.

Are there any other causes of this?

The structure of the project is as follows:

```
Parent
 |_ Child1
 |_ Child2
 |_ dist-proj
```

The parent pom has the following sections:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<modules>
    <module>Child1</module>
    <module>Child2</module>
    <module>dist-proj</module>
</modules>
```

The dist-proj pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>dist-proj</id>
            <phase>assembly</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And the assembly file:

```
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
    <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
    <includes>
        <include>groupid:Child1</include>
        <include>groupid:Child2</include>
     </includes>
          <binaries>
             <outputDirectory>${project.build.finalName}</outputDirectory>
             <unpack>false</unpack>
             <dependencySets>
                <dependencySet>
                   <includes/>
                   <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependencySet>
                <dependencySet>
                   <includes/>
                   <scope>runtime</scope>
                   <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
                </dependencySet>
             </dependencySets>
       </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I assume that your parent pom contains the configuration of the maven-assembly-plugin in the pluginManagement section ? Or do you have it in the build-section? If yes than remove it. Furthermore i assume that the phase in the dist-projec pom where you bound the maven-assembly-plugin to is not "assembly" cause such a life-cycle-phase does not exist. You can bound it to the "package" phase for example.

Comment: Yes it is in the pluginManagement section. Also, you're right about the lifecycle binding, it used to be bound to package, but I took it out to facilitate debugging. I thought there would be an assembly phase, but a nonexistant one works just as well.

Comment: Does you dist-project pom has the packaging "pom" ?

Comment: Yes it does. Sorry, I would've put the entire pom up but I was trying to keep the question concise.

Comment: Why are you calling mvn package and than the supplemental goal: assembly:assembly? Why not simple mvn package ? If you configured the maven-assembly-plugin correct than everything should work well...Does mvn clean package work correct and produces the correct archive? Is this all in your assembly-descriptor, it doesn't look complete?

Comment: I took the package lifecycle binding out of the assembly descriptor so that mvn package would just build the individual module packages. I wanted assembly to create the project jar (including all dependencies), which is why mvn clean package works, but doesn't create the jar I want. I have to call mvn package assembly:assembly specifically.

Answer (score 18):

I have encountered this error as well. Looking at the Plexus Archiver source code, the hasNext method returned by getResources in AbstractArchiver calls itself every time it encounters a class or artifact it has already seen. This is causing it to run out of stack space even on medium size projects.

For now the easiest way to fix it is to increase your stack space via MAVEN_OPTS e.g.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xss2m
```

See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-549 for more details

Answer (score 1):

To create only a jar which contains all dependencies you can simply use the [predefined descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
           <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes but I wanted to do a little more, like not unpack the dependent jars and also to have transitive filtering on runtime libraries.

Comment: If you like to change the default behavior just use the given descriptor (copy it from the web-sites) and change it appropriately.

Comment: That actually is what I did :) I used the jar-with-dependencies descriptor as a template and made a few modifications to do what I wanted.

Comment: After upgrading the maven assembly plugin to version 2.2.1 (instead of the implicit one) I din't get the stackoverflow error anymore.